# redirect awk information to stdout

Tags: cpu-usage, awk, pipe

I am trying to gather information for CPU use for all the processors in a text file.

`mpstat -P ALL -u 1 | awk '{print $4}' > cpu.txt`

&&

`mptat -P ALL -u 1 | awk '{print $4}' | tee cpu.txt`

Neither of them seems to work when piped.

Any suggestions to get this working.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
while true; do
    mpstat -P ALL | awk '{print $4}' >> cpu.txt
    sleep 1
done
```

Control-C to stop when you have enough data.

Comment: Any way I can execute this command in Python?

say e.g 

`subprocess.call('mpstat -P ALL | awk '{print $4}' >>cpu.txt', shell=True)`

Comment: Well, you probably need to escape the quotes in the string.